# VBA concatenation is not working (Calling Shell in VBA)

Tags: string, vba, cmd

I have the following vba scrip that works fine:

```
Call shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe""   C:\Users\OEM\Documents\R\file.R", vbNormalFocus)
```

However when I define a filepath variable:

```
Dim fp As String
fp = "C:\Users\OEM\Documents\R\file.R"
```

and try:

```
Call shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe""   & fp & file.R", vbNormalFocus)
```

the code does not work, I know this is a concatenation problem but I'm struggling to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another double quote, but you are probably also going to have more problems if you don't check your values as you go. For example, you will also need to add a space.

I suggest changing your code to work like this, and then you can see what path is being used:

```
Dim fp As String 
Dim sPath As String

fp = "C:\Users\OEM\Documents\R\file.R"

'added double-quote and space right after .exe"
sPath  = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"" " & fp 

'here's where you'll figure out your issues:
Debug.Print sPath 

Call shell(sPath, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: I just found a second double-quote issue. See in-code comments.

Comment: It's one too few, not one too many. Should have been `"""C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"" " & fp`

Comment: @GSerg good point. He will also need a space. He should be able to figure that all out if he writes his code on multiple lines and checks his values, which is really what I'm driving at. Teaching someone to fish, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks guys I was able to make it work, just need a template for a correct string. The debug.print command is a lifesaver. Really useful.